# Why must I use TextBoxFor to post values back to my controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to post a model back to my controller.  I'm not sure why TextBoxFor works and TextBox does not.

```
@ModelType Models.myModel
@Code
    ViewData("Title") = "Foo"
End Code

@Using (Html.BeginForm())
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.Value)         <--- works
@Html.TextBox(Model.Value)                    <--- does not work
@Html.TextBox("Value", Model.Value)           <--- works! (per answer below)


@<input type="submit" value="Save" />

End Using
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html.TextBoxFor creates right input type="text" with correct name value. You mustn't use it, but it helps in this case. Same result may be achieved even with html code:

```
<input type="text" name="Value" value="@Model.Value" />
```

Main point for asp.net mvc model binders is correct names for html controls. Html.TextBox() also does it, using first parameter as html element name, so correct usage of it should be Html.TextBox("Value", Model.Value)